# Loop through contents of folder using file_get_html?

Tags: php, loops

Is it possible to loop through a folder using `file_get_html` for each file?

I'm currently using the following:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://example.local/folder/file1.html');
```

Is it possible to set the path to a folder, then it loops through the folders contents?

```
$html = file_get_html('http://example.local/folder/');
```

The files within the folder could be named anything (there's no set naming convention!) but they will always be html files.

I'm using [simple_html_dom.php](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to get the HTML.

Comment: It is possible, but not like that. I think you need to look at the manual for [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: Not really possible for remote http:// folders.

Comment: @wroniasty It's a local site if that makes any difference.

Comment: PHP does not have a `file_get_html()` function in the standard library. Do you mean `file_get_contents()`, or is this function defined in your application?

Comment: @duskwuff Sorry I should say that I'm using the simple_html_dom.php library.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the general idea:

```
$source = '/some/local/folder/';
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($source) as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    $html = file_get_contents($source.$fileInfo->getFilename());
    //do stuff with $html
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get this working with the http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ library?

Comment: just replace `file_get_contents` with whatever method you have for reading the file contents.